# GPG - "pacman-key --refresh-keys" fails with "gpg: keyserver refresh failed: Permission denied"

Tags: permissions, gpg, keychain

I'm currently having issues with installing a package due to a missing key. My first plan was to updating my keyring however "pacman-key --refresh-keys" fails:

```
[user@hostname ~]$ sudo pacman-key --refresh-keys 
gpg: refreshing 134 keys from hkp://pool.sks-keyservers.net
gpg: keyserver refresh failed: Permission denied
==> ERROR: A specified local key could not be updated from a keyserver.
```

Also tried running it under "su".

```
[user@hostname ~]$ su
Password: 
[root@hostname user]# pacman-key --refresh-keys
gpg: refreshing 134 keys from hkp://pool.sks-keyservers.net
gpg: keyserver refresh failed: Permission denied
==> ERROR: A specified local key could not be updated from a keyserver.
```

Tried running dirmngr manually to see if there are any errors.

```
[user@hostname ~]$ sudo dirmngr < /dev/null
dirmngr[25316]: error opening '/root/.gnupg/dirmngr_ldapservers.conf': No such file or directory
dirmngr[25316.0]: permanently loaded certificates: 141
dirmngr[25316.0]:     runtime cached certificates: 0
dirmngr[25316.0]:            trusted certificates: 141 (140,0,0,1)
# Home: /root/.gnupg
# Config: [none]
OK Dirmngr 2.2.3 at your service
```

I noticed the "error opening '/root/.gnupg/dirmngr_ldapservers.conf'" which had been mentioned on the Arch Linux forums. So I created a blank "/root/.gnupg/dirmngr_ldapservers.conf" and ran dirmngr again. I also get a similar error if I run dirmngr without sudo so I created a blank "/home/user/.gnupg/dirmngr_ldapservers.conf" too.

```
[user@hostname ~]$ sudo dirmngr < /dev/null
dirmngr[28763.0]: permanently loaded certificates: 141
dirmngr[28763.0]:     runtime cached certificates: 0
dirmngr[28763.0]:            trusted certificates: 141 (140,0,0,1)
# Home: /root/.gnupg
# Config: [none]
OK Dirmngr 2.2.3 at your service

[user@hostname ~]$ dirmngr < /dev/null
dirmngr[32757.0]: permanently loaded certificates: 141
dirmngr[32757.0]:     runtime cached certificates: 0
dirmngr[32757.0]:            trusted certificates: 141 (140,0,0,1)
# Home: /home/user/.gnupg
# Config: [none]
OK Dirmngr 2.2.3 at your service
```

Removed both the ".gnupg" folders, ran "pacman-key --init" and then tried "pacman-key --refresh-keys".

```
[user@hostname ~]$ sudo rm -rf /root/.gnupg
[user@hostname ~]$ sudo rm -rf /home/user/.gnupg
[user@hostname ~]$ sudo pacman-key --init
[user@hostname ~]$ sudo pacman-key --refresh-keys
gpg: refreshing 134 keys from hkp://pool.sks-keyservers.net
gpg: keyserver refresh failed: Permission denied
==> ERROR: A specified local key could not be updated from a keyserver
```

After removing both ".gnupg" directories I ran dirmngr again.

```
[user@hostname ~]$ dirmngr --debug-level guru
dirmngr[18151]: enabled debug flags: x509 crypto memory cache memstat hashing ipc dns network lookup extprog
dirmngr[18151]: error opening '/home/user/.gnupg/dirmngr_ldapservers.conf': No such file or directory
dirmngr[18151.0]: permanently loaded certificates: 141
dirmngr[18151.0]:     runtime cached certificates: 0
dirmngr[18151.0]:            trusted certificates: 141 (140,0,0,1)
dirmngr[18151.0]: failed to open cache dir file '/home/user/.gnupg/crls.d/DIR.txt': No such file or directory
dirmngr[18151.0]: creating directory '/home/user/.gnupg'
dirmngr[18151.0]: creating directory '/home/user/.gnupg/crls.d'
dirmngr[18151.0]: new cache dir file '/home/user/.gnupg/crls.d/DIR.txt' created
dirmngr[18151.0]: DBG: chan_3 -> # Home: /home/user/.gnupg
# Home: /home/user/.gnupg
dirmngr[18151.0]: DBG: chan_3 -> # Config: [none]
# Config: [none]
dirmngr[18151.0]: DBG: chan_3 -> OK Dirmngr 2.2.3 at your service
OK Dirmngr 2.2.3 at your service
```

And now I'm completely stuck. I suspected there might be some kind of permissions issue with a file needed by GPG but given that I've deleted both ".gnupg" directories and that they've been regenerated I don't see what's wrong.

I've also tried everything on this wiki page: https://wiki.parabola.nu/Parabola_Keyring everything worked including the "sudo pacman-key --populate archlinux archlinux32 archlinuxarm parabola" command but "pacman-key --refresh-keys" still gave me the permissions error.

Just tried refreshing my keyring with gpg directly:

```
[user@hostname ~]$ sudo gpg2 --refresh-keys
gpg: directory '/root/.gnupg' created
gpg: keybox '/root/.gnupg/pubring.kbx' created
```

Then tried to do it with pacman-key:

```
[user@hostname ~]$ sudo pacman-key --refresh-keys
gpg: refreshing 135 keys from hkp://pool.sks-keyservers.net
gpg: keyserver refresh failed: Permission denied
==> ERROR: A specified local key could not be updated from a keyserver.
```

So that failed. Tried with gpg2 to see if the output was the same:

```
[user@hostname ~]$ sudo gpg2 --refresh-keys
```

There wasn't any output so I doubt that the files it created are related to my current issue.

As a last ditch effort I tried without sudo and got no output:

```
[user@hostname ~]$ gpg2 --refresh-keys
```

Still stuck with this. Even installed kgpg to manually generate a config file for gpg. However, I'm still getting this damn permissions error.

Answer (score 1):

switch keyserver in ~/.gnupg/gpg.conf  the current one defined could well be 404